# previous_post_link and next_post_link show on first and last entries

Tags: wordpress

I have a very simple loop on my single.php page that includes the previous/next post links. For some reason, both links appear on the first and last entries, even though it should only show one or the other. Any idea why this functionality might be broken? It happens in the default theme and doesn't seem to be an issue with a plugin.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
<?php previous_post_link(); ?>
<?php next_post_link(); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: what does it link to when appearing in the first and last post?

Comment: Both "previous" and "next" link to the entry that is either just before or just after it.

Comment: Ok, it turns out that it had something to do with the particular posts. When I deleted all of them and created new ones (with the same exact info), everything works fine. I cannot figure out where the problem was though.

Comment: I had this strange issue, too. I think it was caused by a plugin that bulk-creates the posts (to test the theme). When i deleted all the posts and created some "by hand" everything worked fine. Thanks for your hint.